# Loop through the array and return a `Dropdown.Item` element for each item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to loop through the todos array using the JavaScript map() function. I want to  return a `Dropdown.Item` element for each item. 
When I click the `Dropdown.Toggle` , an empty list expands. `Dropdown.Item` and `Dropdown.Toggle`  are react bootstrap components.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-egxxcl

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [{name: 'A', value: 10}, {name: 'B', value:20}]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
          Change
        </Dropdown.Toggle>

        <Dropdown.Menu >
          {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
            <Dropdown.Item value={todo.value}>{todo.name}</Dropdown.Item>
          })}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle so we can see the behavior and play around with it

Comment: @PouyaAtaei https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-egxxcl

Comment: You've got import errors, check them out

Comment: @PouyaAtaei This is not about import errors. The application normally installs react-bootstrap. In the example on stackblitz I can not install react-bootstrap

Comment: well I can't reproduce the issue in this manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed to `return` from `map` function.

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
     return <Dropdown.Item value={todo.value}>{todo.name}</Dropdown.Item>
})}
```

or shorten,

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => (
   <Dropdown.Item value={todo.value}>{todo.name}</Dropdown.Item>
))}
```

or even shorten,

```
{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => <Dropdown.Item value={todo.value}>{todo.name}</Dropdown.Item>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from the `map` function, you can wrap it in parentheses or without to avoid using the `return` keyword, also don't forget the `key` prop.

I highly recommend using a [linter](https://eslint.org/) to help you catch those small errors

You can also destructure value and name from the map callback function using `({})`

```
({ propName })

<Dropdown.Menu>
  {this.state.todos.map(({ name, value }) => (
    <Dropdown.Item key={name} value={value}>{name}</Dropdown.Item>
  ))}
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

Comment: And does `linter` help you catch variables that are declared and not used?

Comment: @Umbro Yes there are tons of "rules" that you can define to make your code consistent and you can combine it with a code formatter to auto format your code on save